# How to find specific solution to PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Equation: *u$_x$* + $\frac{x}{y}$*u$_y$* = 0. Initial condition: *u*(0, *y*) = exp(-*y*$^2$)

My professor found the solution *u*(*x*, *y*) = *f*(*y$^2$* - *x$^2$*) using characteristic curves

He then evaluated *u*(0, *y*) = *f*(*y$^2$*)

His final answer was *u*(*x*, *y*) = exp(-(*y*$^2$-*x*$^2$)).

I understand everything up until the last two lines - how did he get from the $2$nd to last line to the final line of working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution is $u(x,y)=f(y^2-x^2)$ for any function $f$ (which will be determined by the initial condition). Then using the initial condition we obtain

$$u(0,y)=f(y^2)=e^{-y^2}$$

or $f(v)=e^{-v},$ so we have found $f$ which satisfies the initial condition. Then we have the final solution

$$u(x,y)=f(y^2-x^2)=e^{-(y^2-x^2)}$$

Comment: The bits you added really helped. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome! :-)